# finding css display value of a div

Tags: jquery

I have some divs that have a css display of either 'block' or 'none' :

```
$("#divMTR").css("display", "none");
$("#divST").css("display", "block");
```

Is it possible to check what the css display value is for a div in JQuery?  I would like to check what the value is, and on a certain condition change it.

Comment: also remember to look at  jQuery's .toggle() which will toggle the state of an element between .hide() and .show();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the value of a CSS proeprty by writing `$(...).css('propertyName')`.

You may also want to write `if ($('#divST').is(':visible'))` (or `:hidden`), using jQuery's [`.is()` method](http://api.jquery.com/is) (which checks whether an element matches a selector) and the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) pseudo-selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Just use :

```
alert($("#divMTR").css("display"));
```

This will return the value instead of modifying it. It works for most Jquery methods.